# Jquery is undefined

Tags: jquery

i got **'JQuery' is undefined** error while browsing the page in IE 6 but it works with all

browsers (including ***IE 7*** ).can anyone help me.

Comment: You have to make either a new link or paste the code because that's an internal IP-address :D

Comment: WTF dude you linked to an IP address in your local network! Upload your code to a server we can access from the outside if you want some help, or detail your code here.

Comment: with that link, he just made my day ! :-D

Comment: The new external link you posted still links to internal ip addresses for a number of its resources - "http://192.168.1.100/carousel192.js", for instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking in consideration that you actually posted a link to an internal IP Address, I can give you a quick answer (hopping that you have internet connection on the page you are having this problems)

change the script call to:

```
<script 
     type="text/javascript"          
     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Edited your post to remove the self closing since not all browsers support that notation

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this problem, Put your JQuery library at the beginning of all other Javascript libraries.
If your using other libraries like JQGrid or JQuery UI which uses Jquery. then it should look like this..

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> /* First your JQuery lib */
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script> /* Then your JQuery UI or JQGrid */
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously You have to change this also:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.1.100/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="http://192.168.1.100/carousel192.js"></script>
```

into this (also copy this two files into folder named **js** in the same directory where the html file is):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="js/carousel192.js"></script>
```

And do not use Your local IP addresses!